# Split equation in an alignat object

Tags: align, alignat

I have a set of equations that I would like to align the start of the equations, the quantifiers, and in the case of equation 1, the + and = sign.

There are two problems I have not been able to solve:

1. how to align the quantifier with the equation number in the {split environment}
2. how to align a split equation with other equations

I wonder if tabular can be used, but there appears to be no way of manually defining equation numbers. Thanks for any help!

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
\begin{split}\label{1}
C_{g,t}^\mathrm{sum} =& \lambda _{g,t}^{\uparrow}p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} - \lambda _{g,t}^{\downarrow}p_{g,t}^{\downarrow} \\
&+ {\lambda ^\mathrm{FC}}\left( {p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} + p_{g,t}^{\downarrow}} \right) \forall g,t
\end{split}
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{3}
& p_{g,t}^{\mathrm{sum}} = p_{g,t}^{sch} + p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} - p_{g,t}^{\downarrow} &\quad &\forall g,t \label{2} &\\
& c_{t}^\mathrm{sum} = c_{t}^\mathrm{DA} - c_{t}^\mathrm{shed} + \Delta{c_{t}} &\quad &\forall t \label{3} \\
& w_{t}^\mathrm{sum} = w_{t}^\mathrm{DA} - w_{t}^\mathrm{spill} &\quad &\forall t \label{4} \\
& \sum\limits_l {c_{t}^\mathrm{sum}} = \sum\limits_g {p_{g,t}^{sum}}  + w_{t}^{sum} + B_t^F &\quad &\forall t \label{5} \\
& \Delta p_{g,t}^ \uparrow  = p_{g,t}^ \uparrow  - p_{g,t - 1}^ \uparrow &\quad &\gamma_t = 1,\forall g,t \label{6}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

The output is very ugly:

[image: align a split equation in alignat object]

Comment: Avoid the `cmex10` option to `amsmath`. It's there for compatibility with ***very very very*** old TeX distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `split` and with some adjustments:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
\label{1}
&C_{g,t}^\mathrm{sum} = λ_{g,t}^{\uparrow}p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} - λ_{g,t}^{\downarrow}p_{g,t}^{\downarrow}  && \notag\\
& \hphantom{C_{g,t}^\mathrm{sum}}
+ {λ^\mathrm{FC}}\left( {p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} + p_{g,t}^{\downarrow}} \right)
 &&   \forall g,t
\\
& p_{g,t}^{\mathrm{sum}} = p_{g,t}^{sch} + p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} - p_{g,t}^{\downarrow} &\quad &\forall g,t \label{2} \\
& c_{t}^\mathrm{sum} = c_{t}^\mathrm{DA} - c_{t}^\mathrm{shed} + Δ{c_{t}} &\quad &\forall t \label{3} \\
& w_{t}^\mathrm{sum} = w_{t}^\mathrm{DA} - w_{t}^\mathrm{spill} &\quad &\forall t \label{4} \\
& \sum\limits_l {c_{t}^\mathrm{sum}} = \sum\limits_g {p_{g,t}^{sum}}  + w_{t}^{sum} + B_t^F &\quad &\forall t \label{5} \\
& Δp_{g,t}^ \uparrow  = p_{g,t}^ \uparrow  - p_{g,t - 1}^ \uparrow &\quad &\gamma_t = 1,\forall g,t \label{6}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hello, in this case the equation number of the first equation appeared on the second line instead of getting centered between the first two lines, as would have happened if a split environment was used. can one have the split environment AND still have the alignment?

Comment: @cmtappu96 I think that question is better asked in a new thread with all the details like document class etc.

Answer (score 1):

- I removed the `split` environment as `@harish` suggests.
  You don't have to split your equations into two `alignat` environments.
- I moved `&` at the beginning of each line to the left of `=`.
  This makes `=` align.
- I added `\quad` before `+` in the equation 1.
  This makes `+` come right to `=`.
- I fixed some minor errors in the source code.

Here is the output:

[image: output]

and the code:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{2}
  C_{g,t}^\mathrm{sum}
  &= \lambda_{g,t}^{\uparrow}p_{g,t}^{\uparrow}
  - \lambda_{g,t}^{\downarrow}p_{g,t}^{\downarrow} \notag \\
  &\quad + \lambda^\mathrm{FC}
  \left(p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} + p_{g,t}^{\downarrow}\right)
  &\quad & \forall g,t \label{1} \\
  p_{g,t}^{\mathrm{sum}}
  &= p_{g,t}^{\mathrm{sch}} + p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} - p_{g,t}^{\downarrow}
  &\quad &\forall g,t \label{2} \\
  c_{t}^{\mathrm{sum}}
  &= c_{t}^{\mathrm{DA}} - c_{t}^{\mathrm{shed}} + \Delta c_{t}
  &\quad &\forall t \label{3} \\
  w_{t}^{\mathrm{sum}}
  &= w_{t}^{\mathrm{DA}} - w_{t}^{\mathrm{spill}}
  &\quad &\forall t \label{4} \\
  \sum\limits_{l} c_{t}^{\mathrm{sum}}
  &= \sum\limits_{g} p_{g,t}^{\mathrm{sum}}  + w_{t}^{\mathrm{sum}} + B_{t}^{F}
  &\quad &\forall t \label{5} \\
  \Delta p_{g,t}^{\uparrow}
  &= p_{g,t}^{\uparrow} - p_{g,t - 1}^{\uparrow}
  &\quad &\gamma_{t} = 1, \forall g,t \label{6}
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```